# Handling acks and rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I wanted to know/understand ,if any of you faced below issues with Kafka and how do they solved them

1. When there is acks all and “commit failed exception” (which leads Kafka producer publishing the same message multiple times)

2)“Kafka partition re-balancing” ,( which leads to Kafka consumer consuming the same message multiple times)

3. Sometime one or more partition thread stops/non-responsive ,which leads to few partition's messages being unread !!

Thanks !!

Comment: kafka can be easily used to achieve at least once guarantees. From your question it seems that you want to avoid duplicate processing. This is not possible to achieve using kafka.

Comment: Yes among the three  question's , one of them is duplicate processing or idempotency !! My broader question's were to find out what are different issues people are getting , while using Kafka , Apache or Confluent !!